# Deploy Google App Engine failed with timed out

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I have problem deploying my nodejs to app engine with `gcloud app deploy`. In the log file, it keeps reporting this error for about ~20mins

> 2018-02-14 13:48:50,271 DEBUG    root            Operation [apps/billy-cart/operations/d228fad1-a2d3-45fd-9712-e279132f1e26] not complete. Waiting to retry.

then the process ends with

> Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
>   ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Timed out waiting for the app infrastructure to become healthy.

When I check console, I can see my 1 of 2 instances created but traffic is not migrated yet. For the record my app.yaml is simply as

```
env: flex
runtime: nodejs
manual_scaling:
  instances: 2
resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 4
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

How can I troubleshoot this issue? I can't make any deployment

Fyi this is not my first deployment, but it's been acting weird like this lately. I have checked the log of that instance and it already executes my `npm start` command - no error. Also I am running latest gcloud SDK v188.0.1 on Ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an ongoing [investigation](https://issuetracker.google.com/73583699) for this very same error. Although, I've seen similar errors when compute engine quota has been reached. I'd suggest to follow updates from the issue tracker and also, check your project to know if any GCE quotas are reached.